# Using var keyword when defining a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I read some posts here on using `var` keyword when defining a new variable. The posts mentioned how using `var` within a function creates a variable with local scope, whereas not using `var` keyword creates a variable with global scope. Most posts recommend that `var` should always be used. I have a few questions:

1. I am learning JS and I was trying to write a script that counts the number of times a button has been clicked (see below for the code). If in the `else` part of the function `totalClicks` I use `var numclicks = 1;` then the code below does not wor. If I omit the `var` keyword, it works. Is this because for the code to work `numclicks` needs to be a global variable, or is there some other reason? Is this an exception to the rule that `var` should always be used, or is there another way to program this.
2. The first time the button is clicked, the output is `NaN`. It is not clear to me why it is not 1? Following the logic of the code it appears that the variable is set to 1 before it is written to the document. I know this problem gets solved if I add `numclick = 0;` before the function statement. But it is not clear to me why this solves the problem.

Thanks very much for your help.

**CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Count number of clicks</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="button" value="click here" onclick="totalClicks();">
    </form>

Total clicks: <span id="numclicks"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function totalClicks(){
            if (window.numclicks) {
                numclicks++;
            }
            else {
                numclicks = 1;
            }

            document.getElementById("numclicks").innerHTML = numclicks;

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: Slava gives a ore complete answer, but for your info, Javascript has the fairly insane concept of hoisting. Once you understand it it's really simple, until you do things seem really bizzarre. Here is a really short and simple article on it: http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/24/basic-javascript-part-5-hoisting/

Comment: @George Mauer I love the web design of that site :)

Comment: @ George - Thanks for the link. I checked the article, but the following is still not clear. The author says "But function scope means that all variables and parameters declared inside a function are visible everywhere within that function, even before the variable has been declared." If they are visible everywhere, why is the first output `undefined``. What does "visible everywhere" mean?

Comment: @Curious2learn because you coded a very subtle bug into this. Run http://jsfiddle.net/VjpQh/ with your console open and you'll see. The first time it runs it tests if window.numclicks exists. You think it doesn't, right? Because you didn't create it yet. But you did! `<span id="numclicks"></span>` can be (but should NOT be) accessed via `window.numclicks`. In other words, the first time you run, you get NaN because you are doing `(the span)++` which is `NaN` which evaluates to false the second time and you finally get what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first time you define `numclicks`, it needs to be outside of any functions so it becomes global. Using `var` while still defining a variable inside a function does not make it global. Using var on a global variable inside a function will make it a local variable.
2. You have an element with the id of `numclicks`, so `window.numclicks` points to that element by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Count number of clicks</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="button" value="click here" onclick="totalClicks();">
    </form>

Total clicks: <span id="numclicks"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function totalClicks(){
            var numClicks = document.getElementById("numclicks").value;

            if (numclicks > 0) {
                numclicks++;
            }
            else {
                numclicks = 1;
            }

            document.getElementById("numclicks").innerHTML = numclicks;

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this may work, it's an ugly and inefficient substitute for a global variable.

Comment: 9. Stop touching the DOM, damnit!  http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas

Answer (score 0):

1. Of course it needs to be a global variable.

   This is because the scope of the local variable dies as soon as you reach the end of the `totalClicks()` function.
2. I don't know what causes this but setting numclicks to 0 OUTSIDE the function should help. Set window.numclicks to 0 and always use window.numclicks so you can always see which is a global variable. (The global scope is often very practical even though it is often frowned upon in many languages)